# No display on Benq GW2255 model for Raspberry Pi Model B+

Tags: raspbian, boot, hdmi, video, noobs

No display are coming, while booting raspberry model b+ with Benq GW2255 (Only have this monitor).

I had successfully tested PI with PuTTY/SSH. I had made various config changes, that I found on the internet like `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`. I have tried NOOBS and 2014-12-24-wheezy-raspbian OS.

The Pi lights are showing properly.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to put all of them reverted to default that is make them all commented and restart pi..

and read about config.txt

check this too.
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/three-ways-to-display-your-raspberry-pi-on-a-monitor-or-tv/

Comment: I already tried this.

Comment: is your LCD fine?? on other Pi??  And also there are several option on many LCD (if TV) for HDMI VGA TV AV.. Is your LCD is of same kind??

Comment: I have one HDMI port (Monitor). It is working fine.